# Force textbox to be uppercase in UWP (Windows 10)

Tags: c#, uwp, converters, uppercase

I want to force the text a user inputs into a TextBox on a UWP app (for Windows 10) to be uppercase. WinForms and WPF both have a simple way to do this with the built in CharacterCasing, however UWP does not.

I tried two different methods; an online example by [AlexDrenea](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9f78c46-4929-4114-9c3f-a685b2209a7a/cuwphow-can-i-make-text-input-in-a-textbox-uppercase?forum=wpdevelop), and I built a converter myself. In both situations, I found that when I typed "test" into the textbox, the text gets jumbled (for example, "test" appears as "TSTE").

I really thought the converter would work. Any suggestions on what can be done to improve it so it doesn't jumble up the letters?

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="MakeUppercaseEx2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MakeUppercaseEx2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <local:TextToUppercaseConverter x:Name="MyUppercaseConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBox Name="txtExample2" Margin="10" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtExample2, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource MyUppercaseConverter}}" />
        <Button Name="btnDisplay" Margin="10" Content="Display" Click="btnDisplay_Click"/>
        <TextBlock Name="lblStatus" Margin="10" Text="" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace MakeUppercaseEx2
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) {
            lblStatus.Text = "You entered: " + txtExample2.Text;
        }
    }

    public class TextToUppercaseConverter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) {
            string sTypedValue = System.Convert.ToString(value);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sTypedValue)) {
                return "";
            }
            return sTypedValue.ToUpper();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that, since this questions was asked, the property CharacterCasing seems to have been implemented for UWP also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

I will create a `TemplatedControl` that is inherited from `TextBox` and will manage `TextChanged` events inside the `TemplatedControl` so that it can be used anywhere. Also I would make a Property that determines if i want text capitalized always or not. That way i can use the same control in all places necessary.

Below is a simple TextBox Inherited `TemplatedControl`

```
public sealed class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TextBox);
    }

    public CaseType CharacterCasing
    {
        get { return (CaseType)GetValue(CharacterCasingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CharacterCasingProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CharacterCasingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CharacterCasing", typeof(CaseType), typeof(MyTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(CaseType.Normal,(s,e)=>
    {
        TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)s;
        if ((CaseType)e.NewValue !=(CaseType)e.OldValue)
        {
            myTextBox.TextChanged += MyTextBox_TextChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            myTextBox.TextChanged -= MyTextBox_TextChanged;
        }
    }));

    private static void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyTextBox myTextBox = sender as MyTextBox;
        switch(myTextBox.CharacterCasing)
        {
            case CaseType.UpperCase:
                myTextBox.Text = myTextBox.Text.ToUpper();
                break;
            case CaseType.LowerCase:
                myTextBox.Text = myTextBox.Text.ToLower();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        myTextBox.SelectionStart = myTextBox.Text.Length;
    }

    public enum CaseType
    {
        Normal,
        UpperCase,
        LowerCase
    }
}
```

I created a Enum called `CaseType` that will determine what case the `TextBox` should respect when user is typing the text.

and in the `TextChanged` event, i am CaseConverting the text based on `Enum`.

You can use this in XAML like below.

```
<local:MyTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 CharacterCasing="UpperCase"/>
```

You can expand the control with more options for CaseConverting as per your requirement.

Good Luck.

---

**Update**

Here is a [Github](https://github.com/avknaidu/SOIssue46491836) Repo. Feel free to download and compare with what you are doing.

Comment: You may be able to use the TextChanging event to grab the typed text and return the uppercase version. Using this event means you won't even see the original lowercase letter being typed and removed like with TextChanged

Comment: @jsmyth886 I explicitly used `TextChanged` instead of `TextChanging` because in WPF when you set `CharacterCasing` to `Upper` and when you type something, it will not show original Typed Text in lower and then change it to upper. Straight away it will show uppercase. I wanted to replicate the same here.

Comment: @AVK - The code works and it does make it uppercase, but I cannot access the new control from the codebehind. Maybe I am missing something, but if I try to get the text value from the codebehind (for example: string sWhatWasTyped = txtExample.Text; ) I get the error: The name 'txtExample2' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @ThePeter How are you accessing `txtExample2` from your codebehind? can you update your question?

Comment: @ThePeter and to access the Control, if you put this in a separate `Namespace` make sure you add that namespace in code behind.

Comment: @AVK - I added the extra code as requested. When I used your TemplateControl, I just added it inside the existing namespace of the codebehind.

Comment: @AVK - I don't know what the difference is, but you named your control using "xName" (for example: `<local:MyTextBox x:Name="txtExample2"/>`), but I used just "Name" (ie: `<local:MyTextBox Name="txtExample2"/>`). That was the only difference, and once i renamed my control to use the xName format, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I use **CharacterReceived** event of the text box

```
private void TextBox_CharacterReceived(UIElement sender, CharacterReceivedRoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            TextBox TBx = (TextBox)sender;

            if (char.IsLower(args.Character))
            {
                int Pos = TBx.SelectionStart;
                TBx.Text = TBx.Text.ToUpper();
                TBx.SelectionStart = Pos;
                args.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```